# QtQuick: dragging MapQuickItem on a Map

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I want to achieve self-draggable `MapQuickItem`. Simple example:

```
MapQuickItem {
    id: markerItem

    sourceItem: Rectangle {
        id: sourceRect
        color: "red"
        width: 20
        height: 20
        x: 0
        y: 0

        MouseArea {
            drag.target: markerItem
            cursorShape: drag.active ? Qt.ClosedHandCursor : Qt.OpenHandCursor
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
    Drag.active: true
}
```

The point is, if I drag fast, dragging is interrupted as soon as cursor leaves marker. Is there a way to make it work properly?

Comment: @derM, yes it has.

Comment: Then you might try to prevent your problem by having either your `MouseArea.preventStealing: true` or to disable the gestures of the `Map` while the drag is active. I have not worked with `Map` though, so I can't promise you, it'll help.

Comment: @derM, well, neither helped. I found a workaround, though

Comment: Sorry, but ok. Would you share your workaround with the community in an answer please?

Comment: It's cause by coordinate change behaviour I guess. How do you change marker coordinates?

Comment: @someoneinthebox, coordinates are changed by dragging here. In the working example below, geocoordinates are calculated from qml item coordinates

Comment: @Andrei R, I am asking that cause I got your problem and `MouseArea` canceled (`onCanceled` signal) when I remove/add my marker on map if any coordinates changes. When I rewrite code to dynamic change coordinates - interruptions end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround: using separate draggable `QQuickItem` and an anchor `MapQuickItem`:

```
MapQuickItem {
    id: anchor
    sourceItem: Item {}
}

Rectangle {
    id: handle

    property bool dragged: mouseArea.drag.active

    color: "red"
    width: 20
    height: 20
    x: anchor.x - width
    y: anchor.y - height

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        enabled: draggable
        drag.target: handle
        drag.threshold: 0
        anchors.fill: parent
        cursorShape: dragged ? Qt.ClosedHandCursor : Qt.OpenHandCursor
    }

    Connections {
        target: anchor
        onXChanged: if (!dragged) x = anchor.x - width
        onYChanged: if (!dragged) y = anchor.y - height
    }

    onXChanged: if (dragged) anchor.x = x + width
    onYChanged: if (dragged) anchor.y = y + height

    Drag.active: true
}
```

It's not super convenient with dynamically populated `QML Map`, but does the job